# Electric field strength $d$km from a television transmitter of power $P$kW, assuming isotropic radiation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, power, poynting-vector

I think I need to use the Poynting vector to do this, as it is equal to the power per unit area flowing through a surface.

At a distance $d$km from the transmitter, the surface will have a surface area of $A = 4\pi d^2$, giving a Poynting vector of $N = \frac{P}{4\pi d^2}$.

However I am not sure how to use this to find the electric field strength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already on the right track by finding
$$N=\frac{P}{4\pi d^2}.\tag{1}$$

You have the definition of the Poynting vector
$$\mathbf{N}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{B},$$
or taking the amplitudes only (give or take a factor of $2$):
$$N=\frac{1}{\mu_0}EB.\tag{2}$$

You also know that in an electromagnetic wave the field strength
amplitudes are related by
$$E=cB.\tag{3}$$

From (1), (2) and (3)  you can eliminate $N$ and $B$,
and then find $E$ in terms of $P$ and $d$ only.